# Nicer curved lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-graph

Is there a way to make a nicer curved line in the image below, linking two nodes of different graphs?

[image: graphs]

Here is the code I am using :

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,latexsym,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, decorations.pathreplacing,shapes,shapes.geometric,hobby,patterns,babel,matrix,calc,snakes,backgrounds,shapes.multipart,shadows.blur,decorations.markings,positioning,bending,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \SetGraphUnit{1.6}
        \SetVertexNormal[MinSize =6pt,
        LineWidth = .1pt,
        LineColor = Goldenrod,%
        FillColor = Goldenrod]
        \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style = {color = Goldenrod}}
        \SetVertexMath
        \SetVertexLabelOut
        \begin{scope}[rotate=45]
        \Vertices[Lpos=45]{circle}{v_3,v_2,v_1,v_4}
        \coordinate (v_5) at (intersection of v_1--v_3 and v_2--v_4);
        \Vertex[Node,Lpos=45]{v_5}
        \Edges(v_4,v_3,v_2,v_1,v_4)
        \Edges(v_1,v_5,v_4)
        \end{scope}
        \draw [->] plot [smooth] coordinates { (1.225,1.125) (3.25,1.65) (5.7,2.55) (6.8,1.15) (6.525,-.395)};
        \Vertex[x=6.525,y=-.495]{4}
        \Vertex[x=3.475,y=-.495,Lpos=180]{3}
        \Vertex[x=5,y=-1.6,Lpos=-90]{5}
        \Vertex[x=5.9375,y=1.295,Lpos=90]{2}
        \Vertex[x=4.0625,y=1.295,Lpos=90]{1}
        \Edges(1,2,4,3,1,5,2)
        \node[] at(3.475,2.1) {\Large$H$};
        \node[] at(-1.75,2.1) {\Large$G$};
        \draw [->] plot [smooth] coordinates { (-1.125,-1.233) (1.35,-1.95) (4.05,1.19)};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The encircles sections of the next picture makes the whole lines not smooth looking, I would want something that is more natural.

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tension`. I could not compile your code, as there seems to be a lot of custom things. Here is the relevant part with improved curves in red:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->] plot [smooth,mark=*] coordinates { (1.225,1.125) (3.25,1.65) (5.7,2.55) (6.8,1.15) (6.525,-.395)};
\draw [->] plot [smooth,mark=*] coordinates { (-1.125,-1.233) (1.35,-1.95) (4.05,1.19)};
\draw [->,thick,red] plot [smooth, tension=0.8] coordinates { (1.225,1.125) (3.25,1.65) (5.7,2.55) (6.8,1.15) (6.525,-.395)};
\draw [->,thick,red] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates { (-1.125,-1.233) (1.35,-1.95) (4.05,1.19)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Improved curves]

Comment: Ohhhh wow, that is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much 